# Database connection from eclipse missing drivers

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jdbc, jboss

so i'm working on a web project with hibernate framework and i'm trying to generate my classes from tables of database, but when i try setting up a new a connection profile -> new driver definition, there is no other driver besides generic JDBC Driver, i don't know if i missed something.
so yes please help(btw i already have installed JBoss tools)

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? Below given is not working for me. I see only Generic JDBC in my driver template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Creating a Driver Definition**

Create a driver to connect to a specific database.

1. Select **Window > Preferences** from the main menu bar.
2. Expand Data Management > Connectivity and select Driver Definitions.
3. Click Add.
4. In the Name/Type tab, select a driver template.

   1. (Optional) Select a Vendor Filter to display only those databases for a specific vendor.
   2. Select a driver template.
   3. (Optional) Modify the Driver Name if a driver definition with this name already exists.
5. In the JAR List tab, indicate the path to the JAR or ZIP file associated with the driver.

   1. Click Add JAR/Zip.
   2. Browse to the location of the JAR or ZIP file.
   3. Click Open.
6. (Optional) In the Properties tab, modify the default properties for the driver definition template.

   - Note: Options in the Properties tab vary based on database server type. You can edit or enter a property in the Value box.
7. Click OK.

Source: https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.doc.user%2Fdoc%2Fhtml%2Fasc1229700372057.html

Comment: In my eclipse, it shows only Generic JDBC as available template. How to resolve this?

Comment: Hi there, eclipse is constantly changing, and it changed quite a bit since 2018. In the end, you need to add the JAR to classpath somehow, there are many ways to achieve this. Nowadays mostly you should resolve this via maven / gradle.